# Extending scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, scaffolding

Is there some way, to trigger my own generator after the scaffold generator is done?

Something like `rails g scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer` will trigger my_generator created by `rails generate generator my_generator`

Comment: Just curious if you ever figured this out?

Comment: @excid3 I post an Answer, I hope I described it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[excid3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277994/excid3)

I solve this in another way.

Originally my thought was:

- I run a scaffold generator
- IT generates all standard files
- Then it will run my own scripts (generators) after

You can customize scaffold workflow [as the documentation says](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow)

So I defined a scaffold generator like this

`config/application.rb`

```
# resource_controller defines which generator to use 
# for generating a controller when using rails generate the resource. 
# Defaults to :controller.

# scaffold_controller different from resource_controller, defines which generator 
# to use for generating a scaffolded controller when using rails generate scaffold. 
# Defaults to :scaffold_controller.

config.generators do |gen|
  gen.orm :active_record
  gen.template_engine :haml
  gen.test_framework :rspec,
                     fixtures: true,
                     view_specs: true,
                     helper_specs: true,
                     routing_specs: true,
                     controller_specs: true,
                     request_specs: true
  gen.helper :helper_and_policy
  gen.scaffold_controller :controller_with_smart_listing
  gen.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

As you can see I only changed `gen.scaffold_controller` which suits to my problem. But I think there is an option for changing a scaffold model generator as well.

Then I created a folder for my generator `lib/generators/rails/controller_with_smart_listing/`

I do not remember how I generate this structure but I share files in a [repository](https://github.com/Kani999/scaffold_generator)